# Uploading image whilst retaining other form data

Tags: node.js

```
<form id="test-form" action="/upload" method="POST">
    <input type="file" id="wizard-picture" name="picture">
    <input name="first_name" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="First Name">
</form>
```

---

```
app.post("/upload", function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

---

I do see my "first_name" show up in req.body, but not "picture".
I changed the enctype to "multipart/form-data", and everything is gone. I got an empty result. I've tried some packages like Multer, I followed every step, but it is still not working.

I want to both upload the image and receive the rest data coming from the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For file uploads, I'd suggest using Multer. For this, see https://github.com/expressjs/multer. It handles file uploads the best way possible. Getting the image just by req.body will not work. Examples for Multer are provided on their GitHub.

Comment: Multer is a middleware. But I want to upload inside app.post("xx", function(req, res){  here}). Are there any package can do this?

Comment: Yes, Multer. The call would then be app.post ("xx", multer.smth (...), function (req, res) { stuff }). The req-variable then contains all the file data, and the file is stored on the server.